# Multiple Doctypes in a single HTML Document

Tags: html, browser, doctype

If a HTML document has two doctypes, how will the doctypes affect the rendering of the page and which doctype would the browser pick? Is having two (or more) doctypes in a single document valid or confusing?

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
<html>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use 2 doctypes? Most likely, the first one will set the page and the second one will make it invalid

Comment: ever in my question did I mention I'm using two doctypes? I saw implementations of such on the internet and asked out of curiosity. I'd never use double doctypes on my side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only a single doctype declaration is permitted. This follows rather directly from the HTML specifications as well the HTML5 drafts, and it can also be checked using a [validator](http://validator.w3.org).

Thus, there is no specification of what *should* happen. The natural expectation is that since browsers process the doctype declaration only in “doctype sniffing” when deciding on the browser mode ([Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) vs. Standards Mode), only the first doctype declaration takes effect and the other is ignored.

This can be tested e.g. as follows (using an HTML 3.2 doctype, which triggers Quirks Mode on all doctype-sniffer browsers):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<title>Testing duplicate doctype effect</title>
<script>
document.write(document.compatMode);
</script>
</html>
```

This displays “CSS1Compat” (= Standards Mode), whereas swapping the doctype declarations causes “BackCompat” (= Quirks Mode).

Comment: "Only a single doctype declaration is permitted... Thus, there is no specification of what should happen" - I'm not convinced the bad guys always play by the rules ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the very first `DOCTYPE` is used by the browser and it's against the specification to have more than one in a document.

I think (not sure) that the only situation when multiple `DOCTYPE`-s *may* be valid is when using IE conditional comments. Browsers other than IE won't see those, of course.

I remember reading a blog entry (can't find it now, so I may be wrong in this) but some (most?) browsers even ignore the DOCTYPE if it's not the first thing they encounter. (This may have been a bug that got fixed since.)

Here's W3School's reference page about `DOCTYPE`:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: What I've seen are examples without conditional comments. I do recall the part about ignoring doctype if it's not the first thing - even whitespace

Comment: @mauris I think those were invalid HTML documents - most browsers would ignore both `DOCTYPE`-s and try to look for hints as they parse the document to see how to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple **DOCTYPE**-s in your HTML page then browser will consider first one, browser parse the DOM line by line. Once browser get DOCTYPE then it will stop looking for other doctypes and will jump to search for HTML tag.

> In the above question HTML-5 DOCTYPE is mentioned first and then
>   HTML-4, according to this browser will render things as HTML-5 doctype

It is better to try once in http://www.w3schools.com/ ... Try to use 'code' or 'kbd' or 'dfn' or 'samp' or 'strong' tag by mentioning both doctypes by priority.